# How to modify beans defined in a spring container

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I have two xml files defining beans for the springframework (version 2.5.x):

```xml
containerBase.xml:
<beans>
    <bean id="codebase" class="com.example.CodeBase">
        <property name="sourceCodeLocations">
            <list>
                <value>src/handmade/productive</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

... and

```xml
containerSpecial.xml:
<beans>
    <import resource="containerBase.xml" />
</beans>
```

Now I want to adjust the property `sourceCodeLocations` of bean `codebase` within `containerSpecial.xml`. I need to add a second value `src/generated/productive`.

**A simple approach** is to override the definition of `codebase` in `containerSpecial.xml` and add both values, the one from `containerBase.xml` and the new one:

```xml
containerSpecial.xml:
<beans>
    <import resource="containerBase.xml" />

    <bean id="codebase" class="com.example.CodeBase">
        <property name="sourceCodeLocations">
            <list>
                <value>src/handmade/productive</value>
                <value>src/generated/productive</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Is there a way to extend the list without redefining the bean?**

**EDIT 2009-10-06:**

The purpose of this is to have a shared standard container `containerBase` that is used by a lot of different projects. Each project can override/extend some properties that are special for that project in its own `containerSpecial`. If the project doesn't override, it's using the defaults defined in `containerBase`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s08.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors) to change the bean's metadata before the Spring container instantiates the CodeBase bean.  For example:

```
public class CodebaseOverrider implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private List<String> sourceCodeLocations;

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {        
        CodeBase codebase = (CodeBase)beanFactory.getBean("codebase");
        if (sourceCodeLocations != null)
        {
            codebase.setSourceCodeLocations(sourceCodeLocations);
        }
    }

    public void setSourceCodeLocations(List<String> sourceCodeLocations) {
        this.sourceCodeLocations = sourceCodeLocations;
    }

}
```

Then in contextSpecial.xml:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="context1.xml" />

    <bean class="com.example.CodebaseOverrider">
        <property name="sourceCodeLocations">
            <list>
                <value>src/handmade/productive</value>
                <value>src/generated/productive</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: CodebaseOverrider is not quite what I'm looking for, but with this approach I could write a CodebaseListExtender easily. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  A bean definition can have a "parent" attribute that references a parent bean definition.  The new "child" definition inherits most of the properties of the parent and any of those properties can be overridden.

See [Bean Definition Inheritance](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions)

Also you can use [Collection Merging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#collection-merging) to merge the list property definition from the parent and child bean definitions.  This way you can specify some list items in the parent bean definition and add more items to it in the child bean definition.

Comment: But then there are two beans. "codebase" and the one in "containerSpecial.xml". From the application I only want to find one bean. And I don't want to make the bean "codebase" in "containerBase.xml" abstract, because it's needed from somewhere else.

Comment: You don't have to name both beans "codebase" they can have unique names. Also, you don't need to make the parent bean abstract that is not a requirement, only an option.

Comment: By the way you also need to lookup "collection-merging".  It solves the problem of needing to re-specify collection items that are already specified in the parent bean definition.

Comment: But then I still have two beans of class "com.example.CodeBase". My Application calls XmlBeanFactory.getBeansOfType( CodeBase.class ). So I really want to have only one bean.

Comment: In that case use the abstract keyword on the parent bean as suggested in the reference example; bean definitions that are marked abstract will not be returned by getBeansOfType.

You said in your first comment that the parent bean definition (which would now be abstract) is needed from somewhere else which is okay because being abstract doesn't disable it's use only it's instantiation.  So wherever it's needed elsewhere you can make a new child definition that is also not abstract.

Answer (score 1):

3 approaches:

1. Simple: have two lists defaultSourceCodeLocations and additionalSourceCodeLocations and have your accessor methods check both of these (or combine them). I've seen this done in some frameworks - a default list of handlers is populated then additional user created ones are added...
2. More complicated but keeps the original class clean: You could then create a CodeBaseModifier class. This would have a init-method to alter an injected instance of the bean.

   ```
   <bean id="codebaseModifier" class="com.example.CodeBase" init-method="populateCodeBase">
       <property name="sourceCodeLocations" ref="codebase"/>
       <property name="additionalSourceCodeLocations">
       <list>
           <value>src/handmade/productive</value>
       </list>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ```

If you wanted to make this really generic you could make a bean modifier that would do this by reflection. Be careful of the ordering if use this approach. Dependent beans of CodeBase would have to make sure this class was instantiated first (with depends on)

3   A variation on 2... Instead of directly creating a CodeBase class instead create a factory that returns a populated bean. This factory could then be configured with Spring in a similar fashion to 2. Have a defaultSourceCodeLocations and additionalSourceCodeLocations

Unless you need a lot of extensible properties I would go with option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to define the list in a properties or other configuration before hand?

It seems like the app configuration and wiring are tightly coupled.  From my experience, if it is hard to do something in Spring, likely there is a different easier way to do it.

Comment: I'm free do it the best way. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Properties files are a simple system configuration and can be injected into spring beans via Properties objects.  I have used them for similar default/container properties.  

To get list support, delegate a method to parse the list from the Properties object.


config.default.properties
---------------------------
source.locations.1=src/handmade/productive
source.locations.2=src/handmade/productive1



config.container.properties
---------------------------
source.locations.1=src/container/productive
source.locations.2=src/container/productive1

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 3.0, you can specify merge="true" on the 'list' tag. See http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-97501.html for details.